# bootstrap modal background black

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

when I open the modal the background turns black instead of having opacity to 0.5 or something.

what can i do to fix this ? I use bootstrap 3.2

here is some css:

```
.fade.in {
opacity: 1;
}
.modal-open .modal {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
.fade {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
-o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
.modal {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1050;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
outline: 0;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

I changed opacity to 0.5 in .fade.in it worked but the modal itself was trasparent !

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?  Can you post your CSS?

Comment: By default this should be working fine. Agreed, Browser? Check to see if the opacity rule on .modal-backdrop.in is being overridden by anything.

Comment: @AaronJones yes it was working but when I changed some of the code it was like this

Comment: @AaronJones you're right I overridden .modal-backdrop.in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For bootstrap version 3 the `.fade.in` opacity should be set to `1` and when the modal is initiated then `.modal-backdrop.in` should be set to `.5` at least that's the code that is being used on OOTB bootstrap.